# How to change options of bootstrap datetimepicker after initialization?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, dom

I am using the bootstrap date time picker jQuery plugin by eonasdan: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

I initalize it like so:

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
          format: 'MM DD YYYY',
          inline: true,
          daysOfWeekDisabled: [0,6]
});
```

After initializing the calendar, I want to be able to change the contents of the daysOfWeekDisabled array (an option) based on user input from an html form dynamically. I was wondering whether there is a possible solution for this, as I have scoured the docs and Google but wasn't able to find an adequate answer. I am a beginner in javascript.

Would the solution entail modifying the js file of the plugin or is there some simple javascript code you can write to do this? Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As doc mention: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/

> All functions are accessed via the data attribute e.g. $('#datetimepicker').data("DateTimePicker").FUNCTION()

so you can change daysOfWeekDisabled by using following colde:

```
$('#datetimepicker').data('DateTimePicker').daysOfWeekDisabled([1, 2]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much weigreen! I read that and I was confused by how it was asking for FUNCTION(). Thanks so much, this was a god send and you rock!

Comment: Should this work for endDate() too?    e.g.      
$(elm).data('DateTimePicker').endDate($(elm).attr("max"));      i have multiple datepickers and i want to set the max date from an attribute.